# Tables/Views/SP/Functions could not be fetched

Tags: mysql-workbench, macos

Tengo un problema con MySQL Workbench y es que a pesar de tener tablas dentro de los `schemas`, no puedo acceder a ellas. Tengo la versión `8.0.20.CE` de `MySQl`. Trabajo con Mac OS Catalina, y el error dice:

> -Error loading schema content  Error Code: 1558 Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100411. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error-.

Comment: Ya hiciste lo que te dice el error? ejecutar `mysql_upgrade`

Comment: Es que creo que no sé cómo se hace. Soy nuevo en todo esto, y estoy totalmente atascado...

Answer (score 0):

En la consola de tu Mac;

```
mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta: -bash: mysql_upgrade: command not found;  Es que no es posible trabajar con MySQL Workbench en Catalina?

Comment: Si es posible, yo lo utilizo sin problemas,  lo que podrías probar es lo siguiente, en la consola escribes source ~/.bash_profile, enter, y luego el comando que te indiqué en la respuesta.

Comment: Aún nada...sigo teniendo este error: -bash: /Users/brooky/.bash_profile: No such file or directory. He actualizado la shell pensando que pudiera ser eso, pprque me lo pedía el terminal... y nada. Hay alguna forma de hablar directamente contigo?